# How to use script arguments in AWS DataPipeline SQLActivity?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to execute an unload command on Redshift via Data Pipeline. The script looks something like:

```
unload ($$ SELECT *, count(*) FROM (SELECT APP_ID, CAST(record_date AS DATE) WHERE len(APP_ID)>0 AND CAST(record_date as DATE)=$1) GROUP BY APP_ID $$) to 's3://test/unload/' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/Test' delimiter ',' addquotes;
```

The pipeline looks something like this:

```
{
"objects": [
{
"role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
"subject": "SuccessNotification",
"name": "SNS",
"id": "ActionId_xxxxx”,
"message": "SUCCESS: #{format(minusDays(node.@scheduledStartTime,1),'MM-dd-YYYY')}",
"type": "SnsAlarm",
"topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxx:notification"
},
{
"connectionString": “connection-url”,
"password": “password”,
"name": “Test”,
"id": "DatabaseId_xxxxx”,
"type": "RedshiftDatabase",
"username": “username”
},
{
"subnetId": "subnet-xxxxxx”,
"resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
"role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
"name": "EC2",
"id": "ResourceId_xxxxx”,
"type": "Ec2Resource"
},
{
"failureAndRerunMode": "CASCADE",
"resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole",
"role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
"pipelineLogUri": "s3://test/logs/",
"scheduleType": "ONDEMAND",
"name": "Default",
"id": "Default"
},
{
"database": {
"ref": "DatabaseId_xxxxxx”
},
"scriptUri": "s3://test/script.sql",
"name": "SqlActivity",
"scriptArgument": "#{format(minusDays(node.@scheduledStartTime,1),"MM-dd-YYYY”)}”,
"id": "SqlActivityId_xxxxx”,
"runsOn": {
"ref": "ResourceId_xxxx”
},
"type": "SqlActivity",
"onSuccess": {
"ref": "ActionId_xxxxx”
}
}
],
"parameters": []
}
```

However, I keep getting the error: **The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.**

I just can't get it to work. I have tried using `?`, `$1` and I even tried putting the expression `#{format(minusDays(node.@scheduledStartTime,1),"MM-dd-YYYY”)}` directly in the script. None of them works.

I have looked at the answers to [Amazon Data Pipline: How to use a script argument in a SqlActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481264/amazon-data-pipline-how-to-use-a-script-argument-in-a-sqlactivity) but none of them are helpful.

Does anyone has idea how to use script argument in SQL Script in  AWS Data Pipeline?