# Can use script arguments with ScriptUri in aws ShellCommandActivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a use case where I needed to pass in a script argument to a `BASH` script as specified in the `scriptUri` of the `ShellCommandActivity`. The `AWS` documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html) mentiones that `The scriptArgument can only be used with command; Using it with scriptUri causes an error.`.

But looking at the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27481264/4380130) it appears to be possible, has anyone else tried this before and got it working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we could pass in script arguments with `scriptUri` as below and it worked for me.

```
scriptUri: "s3://location"
scriptArgument: ["%arg1%","%arg2%"]
```